# Load png with OpenTK and MonoDroid

Tags: android, image, xamarin.android, opentk

I'm looking for an example of loading a png-file on MonoDroid using OpenTK. Anyone?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put [TexLib](http://www.opentk.com/project/TexLib) into your code and do the following:

1. save the texture into your Assets folder and give it the Build Action "AndroidAsset"
2. Add the following function to the TexLib.cs:

   ```
   public static int CreateTextureFromStream (InputStream stream)
    {
        return CreateTextureFromBitmap (new Bitmap (Bitmap.FromStream (stream)));
    }
   ```
3. Call the function with your asset:

   ```
   int textureId = TexUtil.CreateTextureFromStream (Assets.Open ("my_texture.png"));
   ```